# The inferred type of active recognizer - one is option and another is not

Tags: f#

I have the following code. For the last two `match`, the first `period` has type of `DateTime option` and the second one has type of `int`. Why the second one doesn't have option?

```ml
let (|Integer|_|) (str: string) =
   let mutable intvalue = 0
   if Int32.TryParse(str, &intvalue) then Some(intvalue)
   else None

let (|DateyyMM|) (str: string) =
    let mutable date = new DateTime()
    if DateTime.TryParseExact(str, 
                              "yyyyMM", 
                              Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
                              Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              &date) 
    then Some(date)
    else None

let (|ParseRegex|_|) regex str =
   let m = Regex(regex).Match(str)
   if m.Success
   then Some (List.tail [ for x in m.Groups -> x.Value ])
   else None

.....
match url with
| ParseRegex "....." [DateyyMM period] -> //period type is DateTime option
......

match downloadLink.Url with
| ParseRegex "....." [name; Integer period] -> // period type is int
......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second case has no option because you added `_|` at the end of the declaration.

This is setup to allow for a shorthand in a match - so that rather than

```
match x with
|Some_long_function(Some(res)) -> ...
|Some_long_function(None) -> ...
```

you can just do

```
match x with
|Some_long_function(res) -> ...
|_ -> ...
```

See the MSDN page on active patterns for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx (in particular the secion on partial patterns)